# Not able to insert into MongoDB Atlas using Pymongo

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, mongodb-atlas

```
import pymongo
import dns
import pandas as pd

from pymongo.mongo_client import MongoClient

uri = "mongodb+srv://<username>:<password>@cluster0.rifrpxv.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority"
# Create a new client and connect to the server
client = MongoClient(uri)
# Send a ping to confirm a successful connection
try:
    client.admin.command('ping')
    print("Pinged your deployment. You successfully connected to MongoDB!")
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

This works so far and I'm able to connect.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file)
data = df.to_dict(orient = 'records')
db = client['database']
db.collections.insert_many(data)
```

When I run this i get:
 `OperationFailure: Unsupported OP_QUERY command: insert. The client driver may require an upgrade. For more details see https://dochub.mongodb.org/core/legacy-opcode-removal`

I checked python version (3.8.3) and pymongo version (4.6) and mongodb version (6.0). Based on the docs here: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/drivers/pymongo/ everything should be compatible but I still can't connect.

Any help much appreciated!

I tried updating all versions to most recent but still not able to connect.

Comment: I don't know python so can't really help in details, but this error says that you use quite old driver with new server, so I assume that somehow you use much older pymongo than 4.6

Comment: solved...had to revert pymongo to 4.1 for compatability

Answer (score 0):

solved...had to revert pymongo to 4.1 for compatability

Comment: python 4.6 should also work here